# c++ more effective way to write this two lines of code comperison to one short line

Tags: c++, optimization

Is there something like short if else `= (cond) ? true : false` statement, but to pass the result of condition to `{ }`? Or maybe some other ideas how to write this kind of code more elegant?

```
double t_day = day * 0.15;
if (t_day < 1) { t_day = 1; }
```

maybe something like

```
double t_day = (day * 0.15) ? day * 0.15 : 1;
```

but without additional calculating?

Comment: Looks like `std::max`.

Comment: This is a great example of "meaningless optimization".  Either one is fine.  Stick to the one that makes the code more readable to you.

Comment: looks like a typo in `double t_day = (day * 0.15) ? day * 0.15 : 1;` - did you mean `(day * 0.15) > 1` ? (That might hint as to which one you find easiest to write correctly)

Comment: duffymo is completely right, as both code samples will produce exact same machine code (if you are using good compiler, of course).

Comment: less chars and lines = more readable for me :)

Comment: To add to what duffymo said: it's called "common subexpression elimination".

Comment: @duffymo: Bear in mind that the point is not optimization, but not having to repeat the `0.15` twice (which is dangerous).

Comment: less lines = less readable, especially when you use ?: operator... it should be used only when completely necessary.

Comment: You can put your entire program on one line if you want, save preprocessor directives.  Then it would be super readable.

Comment: How about `double t_day = (day * 0.15 < 1) ? day * 0.15 : 1;`? What do you mean by additional calculating? Not to perform the multiplication twice? Then what about `double t_day = ((day *= 0.15) > 1) ? day : 1;`? But that would change the value for `day` variable, making it not usable - at least not with the value it had.

Comment: I mean all that all of your wrote about.  1) more readable, 2) without repining of constant 3) less chars 4) less processor use. in one word: elegant. Sorry for my english. std::max looks great :) and `double t_day = ((day *= 0.15) > 1) ? day : 1;` also nice one :) thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
double t_day = std::max(day * 0.15, 1.);
```

Don't forget the period after the `1` as the compiler will not be able to deduce the correct `double` template parameter (and you end up with weird compiler errors).

Comment: Alternatively (to the . at the end) you can ask for a particular specialization: `std::max<double>(day*0.15,1)`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas nice note. thanks, does not know this before.

Answer (score 8):

Given the three functions:

```
double func1(const double& day) {
  double t_day = day * 0.15;
  if (t_day < 1) { t_day = 1; }
  return t_day;
}

double func2(const double& day) {
  return std::max(day*0.15, 1.);
}

double func3(const double& day) {
  return (day * 0.15 > 1) ? day * 0.15 : 1;
}
```

We can inspect the output from the compiler (e.g. `g++ -O3 -S`):

`func1` becomes:

```
_Z5func1RKd:
.LFB368:
        .cfi_startproc
        movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
        movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
        mulsd   (%rdi), %xmm0
        maxsd   %xmm0, %xmm1
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
        ret
```

`func2` becomes:

```
_Z5func2RKd:
.LFB370:
        .cfi_startproc
        movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
        movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
        mulsd   (%rdi), %xmm0
        maxsd   %xmm0, %xmm1
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
        ret
```

and `func3` becomes:

```
_Z5func3RKd:
.LFB369:
        .cfi_startproc
        movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
        mulsd   (%rdi), %xmm0
        maxsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
        ret
```

Where LC0 and LC1 are the constants 1.0 and 0.15.

For reference Clang's intermediate representation might be easier to read:

```
define double @_Z5func1RKd(double* nocapture %day) nounwind uwtable readonly {
  %1 = load double* %day, align 8, !tbaa !0
  %2 = fmul double %1, 1.500000e-01
  %3 = fcmp olt double %2, 1.000000e+00
  %t_day.0 = select i1 %3, double 1.000000e+00, double %2
  ret double %t_day.0
}

define double @_Z5func2RKd(double* nocapture %day) nounwind uwtable readonly {
  %1 = load double* %day, align 8, !tbaa !0
  %2 = fmul double %1, 1.500000e-01
  %3 = fcmp olt double %2, 1.000000e+00
  %4 = select i1 %3, double 1.000000e+00, double %2
  ret double %4
}

define double @_Z5func3RKd(double* nocapture %day) nounwind uwtable readonly {
  %1 = load double* %day, align 8, !tbaa !0
  %2 = fmul double %1, 1.500000e-01
  %3 = fcmp ogt double %2, 1.000000e+00
  %4 = select i1 %3, double %2, double 1.000000e+00
  ret double %4
}
```

### Conclusion:

They all become a `mulsd` and `maxsd` however you write it. Invest your time in writing things the most natural, easiest to get correct way and let the compiler worry about details like this. I'd say it's `std::max` in this instance since what you're doing is taking the bigger of two values.